# Gallery picker returns Uri with a file scheme on Android 10, how to read it?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contentresolver, android-10.0, android-external-storage

My app has targetSdkVersion = 29 (new scoped storage policy) and has not requestlegacyexternalstorage flag enabled in manifest (i do not want to enable it).

Ways i tried to compose intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
```

Also tried this

```
val galleryIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK).apply {
    type = PICK_INTENT_TYPE
}
flowInterruptBlocker?.blockFlowInterruption()
startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY_INTENT_REQUEST_CODE)
```

Also tried to add a `CATEGORY_OPENABLE` to intent. None of these works.

So, when i send intent to pick image from gallery, some apps from play market return me a Uri with a file scheme, for example: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/sample.jpg

When i try to convert it to bitmap (for setting into imageView) i get EACCES (Permission denied) exception.

I tried to read it with a:

```
java.File Api

contentResolver.openInpuStream()

contentResolver.openFileDescriptor()

ImageDecoder
```

Nothing helps. As i can see i can not read Uri with a file scheme on android 10 (targeting 29 sdk) without requestlegacyexternalstorage flag enabled in my manifest.

If i am wrong, please help me to figure out how to read it.

Mysterious thing about it, that android 11 emulator with app targeting 29 sdk CAN read these type of Uri without requestlegacyexternalstorage flag.

And yes, i have granted READ/WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions.

Comment: Please start your post with a code block in which the used code for the used intent.

Comment: `file:///storage/emulated/.../image.jpeg` Please give full path.

Comment: `s i can see i can not read Uri with a file scheme on android 10` Yes you can but it depends on full path. Thats why i asked,

Comment: Indeed: Android 11 is less restrictive. You have a lot of access then. Google did a step back.

Comment: Such apps from play marked use something like getRealPathFromUr() or are old File explorer apps.. Mostly that function is not usable on Android 10 but apparently they have requested legacy storage permission or came up with some code to determine a file path. Sadly not usable on Android 10. Blame the writers of those apps. (You can mail them).  Please name them!

Comment: @blackapps Thanks for your attention. I added code for intent, provided example of uri i cant open. Can you please provide some info about android 11 less restrictivity. Thank you

Comment: On Android 11 that file uri will be usable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> some apps from play market return me a Uri with a file scheme, for example: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/sample.jpg

Some apps are written by inexperienced developers.

> If i am wrong, please help me to figure out how to read it.

On Android 10, you will not be able to read that `Uri` without `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`.

> Mysterious thing about it, that android 11 emulator with app targeting 29 sdk CAN read these type of Uri without requestlegacyexternalstorage flag.

The "raw paths" feature introduced in Android 11 means that `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` works normally again. So, the recommended approach is to request `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` *plus* use `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`, for consistency between Android versions.

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly for me (I've tested it on Android 8, 10, 11 with targeting sdk 29). Doesn't require `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` and any permissions.

```
private static Bitmap readImage(Uri uri, Context context){
   InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
   Bitmap res = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
   inputStream.close();
   return res;
}
```

and you use it like this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       
    if(data == null || data.getClipData().size() == 0)
       return;

    myImageView.setImageBitmap(readImage(data.getClipData().getItemAt(0).getUri(), this));
                    
}
```